# Concurrency control in REST APIs

Tags: rest, api, concurrency, sql-update, crud

Should a REST API implement concurrency control to control almost simultaneous modifications to a resource?

For example, just imagine an application that acts like a Wiki, where users read, write, and edit articles. Now imagine that user Bob and user Mary modify the same article at the very same time, but Bob updates the article faster than Mary and submits his changes. When Mary submits her changes, she overwrites Bob’s. That’s bad news for Bob because his changes are lost.

What would be the best way to avoid this situation? What techniques are usually used for this?

Comment: This is basically the example on this blog: https://blog.4psa.com/rest-best-practices-managing-concurrent-updates/

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am looking for opinions from people who have faced the same problem and know how they have solved it, apart from what is mentioned in the link you are commenting on. Thank you.

Comment: Typically, I'd present Mary a diff using Google's diff-match-patch (https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) with their changes overlaid on Bob's and ask them to merge their input with the latest update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best way to avoid this situation? What techniques are usually used for this?

In the general case, [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232).

Short version: you combine [validators](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2) with [precondition headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3) to ensure "first writer wins" semantics.  The unsafe request to a resource includes a reference to the expected version.  If the resource isn't on that expected version when your request is handled, you get a [412 Precondition Failed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2) response, and then you choose the appropriate remediation.

Specifically for a shared authoring scenario, like the one you described?  You might want to look into Conflict-free Replicated Datatypes (CRDT).  Dr. Kleppmann's talks are pretty approachable: you might start with this one from [Goto 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCcWpzY8dIA); or look for his book *Designing Data-Intensive Applications*.